# How to apply Firestore @Exclude to all classes that inherit the interface?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an interface that has a getter method like `getType()` which I'll only use locally and do not want to store on Firestore. I tried to mark it with `@Exclude` but still getting stored on Firestore. Marking this method with `@Exclude` on each individual class that inherits this interface works but that's quite a lot of work. Is there any way to carry this `@Exclude` to all sub-classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these attributes are inherited from an interface, as they are an annotation on the implementation and not on the interface. If you create an abstract base class however, they should be inherited from there.

Alternatively, it may be worth having a look at the implementation of the [`CustomClassMapper`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/e65f4876ff61b5791986c249b21cb094c37bd29e/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java) in the Firebase SDK, specifically how it determines whether to [consider getters, setters and fields](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/e65f4876ff61b5791986c249b21cb094c37bd29e/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java).

Answer (score 2):

When you create an interface with an abstract method called "getType()", all the classes that implement that interface should provide an implementation for that method. If you mark the method in the interface with the "@Exclude" annotation, it doesn't mean that all the classes that implement that interface will work the same. Interfaces describe behavior, so even if you would have annotated the method with [Inherited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), this wouldn't have worked either, because:

> Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces **have no effect**.

Why? The reason is really simple, it's because of multiple-inheritance problems that might occur.

Please also note, that the annotations don't execute. The annotations are only "notes" or "markers" that are read by the compiler. One simple example might be "@Override". There are also other annotations that are embedded in the class files and read later by Android at runtime. So remember that annotations don't do anything themselves.

And to answer your question:

> How to apply Firestore @Exlude to all classes that inherit the interface?

By simply adding "@Exlude" annotation in the classes in front of every **public field**, or in front of every **public getter** if you have private fields.

> Is there any way to carry this @Exclude to all sub-classes?

No, there is not. And it makes sense since you always want to map a document from Firestore into an object of a "particular" class. So when you create a new instance of the class, and if the "@Exlude" annotation is present, Firestore will know which field to ignore and which not. So the annotation must be present exclusively in the class and **not** in the interface.